# How can i read embed data discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

iam trying to make my bot **read the complete data in a embed**
and i do want my bot to *send the data in the exact format as the original and inside a embed*
can anyone help me please

```
  bot.on("message", msg => {
      if(msg.embed){
         msg.channel.send(msg.embed.content)
      }
     
     });
```

When i try the above code it says can not read content of undefined

I am a beginner so if i made any mistakes please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `embed` property on the [Message](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object. But there is an `embeds` property instead, which is an array of [MessageEmbeds](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed).

You can iterate through all embeds in the message using:

```js
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
    msg.embeds.forEach((embed) => {
        console.log(embed.title);
        console.log(embed.description);
    });
});
```

However, `description` might not be available if the embed just contains fields or a picture etc. You can see the full list of properties that an embed can contain [here](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed).

If the embed does contain fields, you can use the `fields` property in the MessageEmbed class, which is an array of [EmbedFields](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/typedef/EmbedField).

You can look through all fields in all embeds using this:

```js
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
    msg.embeds.forEach((embed) => {
        let fields = embed.fields;
        fields.forEach((field) => {
            console.log(field.name);
            console.log(field.value);
        });
    });
});
```